# Can you ignore test failures when installing an unmanaged package?

Tags: unit-test, failing-tests, unmanaged-package

I want to install an unmanaged package in our production environment but I know that a couple of tests will fail due to settings specific to our org.

I would like to be able to install it and then deploy the fix on the test class right after deployment. Will I be able to "ignore test failures" or will I need to fix this in sandbox and send it to production on a change set or package.?

I just want to avoid the hassle of having to create a huge change set in the sandbox just to include the changes on the conflicting test method.

Comment: You will need to fix your tests or the package won't install in the first place, you could cheat and prior to that portion of the test if(UserInfo.getOrganizationId()!='SB Org Id') return;